# How to handle account creation and login through multiple means

Tags: security, authentication, oauth

## Authentication flow design

When creating a service that allows users to register and login through more than one way (facebook, twitter, local account), what is the best way to handle the account creation and validation through multiple means?

### In Other Words

Imagine this situation:

- A user creates a normal account by sending his (or possibly anyone's) **email** and **password** (that gets hashed, etc)
- For **convenience**, the user immediately has access to their newly created account (*without verifying their email address*)
- A user then tries to login with an external oAuth service: Twitter, Facebook, etc
- When logging in with facebook, its found that an account was already created (manually) with the same email address

### What is the best way to handle this?

I'm trying to come up with a solution that is both user-friendly (convenient) and secure, and the possible security flaws are scaring me.

### Example

Using the webservice **"Mixlr"** as an example, let's see how they handle this:

- **I** create an account with **YOUR** email address (sucks for you)
- Mixlr instantly logs me in and lets me start using their service (that's convenient)
- They also send me an email to verify my account (even though I'm already using it)
- **YOU** decide that you want to join Mixlr, so you create an account.... but instead of using the classic registration process, you opt to use **Facebook** to create your Mixlr account
- Interestingly, **Facebook** sends you back the same email address that **I** used to create **MY** account
- Mixlr decides to "merge" the accounts, simply adding your **Facebook** account as a new "connected account" in their service

### Therein lies the problem

If **I'm** still logged in, using the service, I technically have some small control over **YOUR**  **Facebook** account....

Isn't that insecure... and frankly, a little sketchy?

Mixlr, however, doesn't let the user log in a "second" time without the user verifying/confirming their email address.

Essentially, I don't know what the middle ground is for convenience and security, without first requiring a user to verify their email address during registration.

Comment: Btw. this should be reported to Mixlr as a security issue...

Answer (score 1):

This would be my suggestion on how to handle this:

**Case 1: User creates an account on your site**

- As your requirement was that the user has direct access to the site without verifying his email address, you should at least make this temporarily. If he doesn't succeed to activate the account in a timely manner, you should delete or inactivate the account.
- Provide a button for connecting other accounts (Facebook, Twitter, etc.) independent of the email address they provide

**Case 2: User clicks on *Login with ...***

- Get the user's email address from the provider

  - If there's already an account with that email on your server, present the user with a screen, where he can log into that account and if successful connect both accounts
  - If he's not known already let him

    - create a local account
    - log in and connect a local account with a different email address
    - or just log him in as a special user without a local account (depends on if you want to support this use case)

You should of course never match something unverified with something verified, so Mixlr does some really bad things here. The user should always have to approve **both** accounts (i.e. log in to both) before you connect them.

Note that for some providers you also can not be sure that the email address that is reported them is really verified.

Comment: Its not exactly the best solution, as it requires some additional login and potential user annoyance, but it is a solution. Thank you so much.

Comment: Well once you have verified the user's email address and if you are sure that the provider already verified it, you could skip some of the steps. But as long as you didn't verify it, the user should be required to login to any account that he wants to have connected.

Answer (score 1):

I would say simply to not merge an unverified account with one created through facebook or other means and that the account created through the third party service would take precedence because they had to authenticate with that account.